# Page keeps refershing when submitting data via a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, data-transfer

Am working on a Laravel project whereby when the user hits submit button on a form (which has hidden input values), I redirect the data to the server-side logic (build with PHP), perform some computation and later redirect to the frontend (as a response inside AJAX success) which works fine, next, I populate the response to some of the inputs of the form and finally call submit method (via jquery).

When I open network tab in the browser,, I see that the data keeps being posted alot of times but I want it to be posted only once without refreshing. Please assist?

**Form**

```
<form 
   id="eazzycheckout-payment-form"
   action="https://api-test.*************************" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="custName" id="custName" value="{{ $first }} {{ $last }}">
   <input type="hidden" id="token" name="token" value="{{ $token}}">
   <input type="hidden" id="amount" name="amount" value="">
   <input type="hidden" id="orderReference" name="orderReference" value="">
   <input type="hidden" id="orderID" name="orderID" value="">
   <input type="hidden" id="merchantCode" name="merchantCode" value="6395866423">
   <input type="hidden" id="merchant" name="merchant" value="*************">
   <input type="hidden" id="outletCode" name="outletCode" value="0000000000">
   <input type="hidden" id="extraData" name="extraData" value="Travel_Purchase">
   <input type="hidden" id="popupLogo" name="popupLogo" value="https://********************svg">
   <input type="hidden" id="ez2_callbackurl" name="ez2_callbackurl" value=" https://digital****************">
   <input type="hidden" id="expiry" name="expiry" value="{{ $newDate}}">

  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top payment" src="{{asset('assets/images-new/mastercard.svg')}}" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title payment">
          <!-- Button user is hitting-->
          <button type="submit" id="submit-cg" value="Checkout" style="cursor: pointer;" class="jenga"> Make Payment </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Hidden form-->
  </form>
```

**AJAX code to submit data to the backend, get response and submit the form via jquery**

```
 var form = $('#eazzycheckout-payment-form');

  $( "form" ).submit(function(e) {
    //Prevent default submission
    e.preventDefault();

    var type = 'jengaapi';
    var quote = $('#quote').val();
    var phone = $('#phone').val();

    var type ={
      'type': type,
      'quote' : quote,
      'phone' : phone,
    };
    //console.log(type);

    //Amount
    var amount = $('#amount');
    var orderID = $('#orderID');
    var  orderRef = $('#orderReference');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'jengaAPI',
        //post data to the backend
        data: JSON.stringify(type),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: "json",
        //get the response
        success: function(response){
            //Populate the fields in the form above dynamically
            amount.val(response.amount);
            orderID.val(response.payment_reference);
            orderRef.val(response.payment_reference);

            //Submit the form
            $('#eazzycheckout-payment-form').submit();


        },
        error: function(errMsg) {
             alert(errMsg);
        }
    }); 
  });
```

Comment: The reason why you keep getting the page refresh that you are describing, is because you have an `action` property with a defined link destination. Upon submitting your form, the user will be redirected to that page. You need to remove that, as your AJAX code already has a defined URL to which your data will be sent to. You also don't want a button type submit to send your form. You simply want a normal button (outside of the form element, this is important), that calls your AJAX function, and `.serialize();` your form. Alternatively you can do a `preventDefault();` upon submitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your form as follow :

```
<form method="GET" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
```

With your submit button having containing an `onClick` function :

```
<button type="submit" onclick="submitForm();">Submit</button>
```

In the `submitForm()` function get the form's data and send them to your API directly using ajax :

```
url = $("form").serialize();
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: 'https://api-test.yoursite.com/api?' + url,
    success: function(data) {
        //Data
    },
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks,, I understood your code,, the problem is that I cant submit via AJAX since am supposed to load an iframe on my browser thats why am using .submit() method in success

Comment: I still don't understand why can't you use ajax?

Comment: The success par of AJAX wont open an iframe,, I tried but it didnt work

Comment: @Patweb that's another question and problem, I replied the question you asked limitied to your original post :)